# Elixir: How to search database data with double spaces

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

In my front end, the data display has only single spaces. However, when I filter my data in search bar, it yields no result. It turns out the data actually has double spaces. But when its being repo.all, the double spaces becomes single spaces. I need to search that data.

I have a regexp which i found which i tried in pgadmin which works. I need to replicate it in my elixir datatable, for specifically, integrating it in ilike function.

The regexp is

```
SELECT trim(regexp_replace(name, '\s+', ' ', 'g')) as col_name
FROM table where col_name = 'TEST  DATA'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a better approach might be to use `%` in place of spaces when searching, I find that this gives me generally better results. Here are [the docs for ILIKE in Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-matching.html), but I'll explain with an example. The `%` character used in `ILIKE` matches any string of characters (including the empty string).

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE col_name ILIKE '%test%data%';
```

The query above will match the example that you've given. Granted, it will also match strings like `"testdata"`, `"test data"`, `"something test something data"`, but I think that in general this approach will return results that a user would expect when entering a search like `"test data"`.

A helper function to do this transformation from user input to a string suitable for Ecto's `ilike` would look like this:

```
defmodule SearchHelpers do
  def to_ilike_search_string(search_string) do
    joined_string =
      search_string
      |> String.split()
      |> Enum.join("%")

    "%#{joined_string}%"
  end
end

# SearchHelpers.to_ilike_search_string("test data")
# => "%test%data%"
```

And you could use it in a query like this:

```
ilike_search_string = SearchHelpers.to_ilike_search_string("test data")

query = from p in Post,
  where: ilike(p.content, ^ilike_search_string)

results = Repo.all(query)
```

Good luck, hope this helps.

Comment: Plain wrong: `'%test%data%'` will match `'test foo bar baz data'`.

Comment: Please read my answer. I acknowledge this point, but make the case that it is closer to the behavior expected by users.